# how to organize files in Tomcat and Apache server?

Tags: apache, jsp, tomcat

I just installed both Apache server and Tomcat, and I read that I should put static html pages in Apache and put dynamic pages, like JSP, Servlets, and all other full Java applications in Tomcat. Specifically, where should they go respectively?

For instance, should html files be placed under /var/www/html?
And all other files under /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/?

Any tutorial for this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're doing it backwards: you're trying to optimize the loading of static resources by serving them using Apache rather than Tomcat, before even knowing how to create and deploy a webapp under tomcat. Learn the basics first, then develop, then deploy, then measure if you have a performance problem, then measure if serving the static resources with Apache would improve anything. Then, and only then, you should think about the best way to use Apache in addition to Tomcat.

Comment: Thanks. But i know the basics of deploying a simple web application in Tomcat, but I heard it's better to use Apache together, since I want to build a real website by myself. So to start with, I want to use Apache too. Thanks. Now I am able to configure Tomcat and Apache properly, so when I type my IP in URL, it can display the default home page in Tomcat with port 80. My question is, if I put a html page under /var/www/html, like helloWorld.html, how should I do that? If I need to test a little further, create a JSP in tomcat, but access it through the html in Apache, how to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

The typical ways to forward requests from Apache to Tomcat involve the use of mod_proxy, mod_proxy_ajp or mod_jk (there might be more). All of them are well documented and basically involve requests that hit your Apache to be forwarded to tomcat if they match certain criteria (like path names) - all nonmatching requests will be handled by Apache, however you configure this one.

However, I'm seconding on JB Nizet's comment: Dividing the serving of different content to Apache and Tomcat is an optimization. It's arguable if you should add this complexity (not that it's *too* complex, but it's more to do than not separating it) when you don't have the need. E.g. if your nonoptimized website can handle 1000 concurrent users, but you'll rarely have more than 10 - don't bother.